# Create new JTable with a button click?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'd like to ask how to make new `JTable`s when button clicked (`actionPerformed`)?
I'd like to add several `JTable`s in that way .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the way how to create one, figure out by yourself how to add more, since you didn't provide any [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

Edited:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Stack extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JTable table;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Add");

    String data[][]={{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},    {"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"}
,{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"}
,{"hey","hey"},{"hey","hey"}};
    String columns[] = {"First","Second"};

    public Stack(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024,768));
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public static void main(String [] a){
        Stack s = new Stack();
        s.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        s.pack();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //panel.removeAll();
        table =new JTable(data,columns);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        repaint();
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm afraid that's not solution of my problem. With your code I'm able to create single JTable instead of many, I'm looking for the way to add several JTables with 1 button

Comment: Could you tell me how to manage the tables? Let's say that with your method I've created 4 tables and I want to add row to the third table. How to do that?

Comment: Than you will have to create array of table's.(table[0], table[1]..) The best way to add row in your table is this:               DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel)table[2].getModel();
model.addRow(new Object[]{"Hello,Hello again"});

Comment: Ye and could you post how to make create array of jtables?

Answer (score 5):

- use [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- then there no reason to `recreate` or `remove then add` [JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)
- all updates for `JTable` and its `Model` must be done on  [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)